# Как можно вернуть из JNI vector<vector<float>>?

Tags: c++, jni

У меня есть вот такая C++ имплементация

```
std::vector<std::vector<float>> const &GetVertices() { return m_Vertices; }
```

Мне нужно вернуть этот вектор в `Java` через `JNI`

Из за того, что это `vector` из `vector`-ов я думаю, что я должен использовать тут `jobjectArray`

вот так

```
extern "C" JNIEXPORT jobjectArray JNICALL
Java_com_google_ar_core_examples_
java_helloar_HelloArActivity_fillListWithData(
JNIEnv *env,
jobject /* this */
)
```

и в `Java` это выглядит вот так

```
public native Object[] fillListWithData();
```

**Вопрос - как конвертировать `vector<vector<float>>` в `jobjectArray`?**

Есть у `JNI` метод который может создать `jobjectArray`

И как потом наполнить этот `array`?

Вот так сейчас выглядит имплементация моего `JNI` метода

```
extern "C" JNIEXPORT jobjectArray JNICALL
Java_com_google_ar_core_examples_java_
helloar_HelloArActivity_fillListWithData(
JNIEnv *env,
jobject /* this */
) {
//verticesVec
vector<vector<float>> verticesVec = initializer->GetVertices(); // THIS 
VECTOR I NEED TO CONVERT TO JOBJECTARRAY
jobjectArray verticesArr = env->NewObjectArray(verticesVec.size(), WHAT 
CLASS SHOULD BE HERE?,NULL);

//HOW TO FILL THE ARRAY HERE??

return verticesArr;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Создайте float array.

```
using namespace std;
vector<vector<float>> verticesVec = initializer->GetVertices();
jclass floatArray = env->FindClass("[F");
if (!floatArray) {
    return nullptr;
}

jobjectArray verticesArr = env->NewObjectArray(verticesVec.size(), floatArray, nullptr);
for (size_t i = 0; i < verticesVec.size(); i++) {
    const vector<float>& vec = verticesVec[i];
    jfloatArray element = env->NewFloatArray(vec.size());
    if (!element) {
        break;
    }
    env->SetFloatArrayRegion(element, 0, vec.size(), vec.data());
    env->SetObjectArrayElement(verticesArr, i, element);
}

return verticesArr;
```